# Graph 2 series of data in real time with pyserial

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, pyqtgraph

I have the following code which makes a real-time graph of the reading of a sensor through the serial port, I would like to graph 2 series of data from the already mentioned port.

How can I do it? Any suggestions?
I've searched for examples, but they only work with static data.
Thanks for your time

This code, real-time graph, of a series of data nothing more.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
import serial

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
p = pg.plot()
p.setWindowTitle('DISTANCIA')
curve = p.plot()
data = [0]
raw = serial.Serial(port="COM4", baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
def update():
    global curve, data
    line = raw.readline()
    data.append(int(line))
    xdata = np.array(data, dtype='float64')
    curve.setData(xdata)
    app.processEvents()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)
```

Comment: PyQt4 or PyQt5? How do you send the information? Do you have any specific format ?, with the information you provide it is impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

I have already done this plotting 2 data using pyserial with Arduino you can have my code and change it according to your requirements. As it was working very great.

```
import sys, serial, argparse
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from collections import deque

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation


# plot class
class AnalogPlot:
# constr
    def __init__(self, strPort, maxLen):
        # open serial port
        self.ser = serial.Serial(strPort, 9600)

        self.ax = deque([0.0]*maxLen)
        self.ay = deque([0.0]*maxLen)
        self.maxLen = maxLen

# add to buffer
def addToBuf(self, buf, val):
    if len(buf) < self.maxLen:
        buf.append(val)
    else:
        buf.pop()
        buf.appendleft(val)

# add data
def add(self, data):
    assert(len(data) == 2)
    self.addToBuf(self.ax, data[0])
    self.addToBuf(self.ay, data[1])

# update plot
def update(self, frameNum, a0, a1):
    try:
        line = self.ser.readline()
        data = [float(val) for val in line.split()]
        # print data
        if(len(data) == 2):
           self.add(data)
           a0.set_data(range(self.maxLen), self.ax)
           a1.set_data(range(self.maxLen), self.ay)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exiting')

    return a0, 

# clean up
def close(self):
    # close serial
    self.ser.flush()
    self.ser.close()    

# main() function
def main():
 # create parser
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="LDR serial")
   # add expected arguments
   parser.add_argument('--port', dest='port', required=True)

  # parse args
  args = parser.parse_args()

  #strPort = '/dev/tty.usbserial-A7006Yqh'
  strPort = args.port

  print('reading from serial port %s...' % strPort)

  # plot parameters
  analogPlot = AnalogPlot(strPort, 100)

  print('plotting data...')

  # set up animation
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1023))
  a0, = ax.plot([], [])
  a1, = ax.plot([], [])
  anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, analogPlot.update, 
                             fargs=(a0, a1), 
                             interval=50)

  # show plot
  plt.show()

  # clean up
  analogPlot.close()

   print('exiting.')


  # call main
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```